# Link hasMany/belongsTo associated objects loaded through separate requests?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember/Ember Data 2.4

I have a simple hasMany belongsTo relationship defined as follows:

```
// models/employee.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  shifts: DS.hasMany('shift', { async: false })
})

// models/shift.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  employee: DS.belongsTo('employee', { async: false })
})
```

I load all employees through an initial request on the homepage of the application. Then, when the use navigates to the calendar page, I fetch shifts for the given week in another requests. The shift JSON includes an employee_id.

After shifts have been loaded, `shift.get('employee')` returns `null`.

How can I associate the newly loaded `shift` records with `employee` records that already exist in the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Data default Adapter (both `RESTAdapter` and `JSONAPIAdapter`) does not expect the association being suffixed with '_id'. Rename `employee_id` to `employee` or customize the Adapter being used.